# ClickOnce deploy - how does it check for application updates?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, desktop-application

I know that I can publish a ClickOnce setup that can check for application updates. I will have to provide a `location` where it will check for updates. I want to know how does it actually check?

My scenario: I would like to distribute my ClickOnce `setup.exe` from my locked-web-portal (needs user to signin). Can I just host a particular `manifest` at `http:/www.mywesbite.com/public_dir/something_here` or do I have to host the entire ClickOnce stuff at that public link?

I do not want to host my ClickOnce `setup.exe` on a public link because I need users to signin to access that setup.exe

Let me know if my question is vague.